# Jenkins Installation failed

Tags: jenkins

Upon installation of Jenkins, I get this error. 
Socks5ProtocolException("SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError('Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05, got 0x47',)",)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I hope you understand that it's super hard for someone else to help you based on the information provided. Please edit your post and be a lot more explicit at what your environment/config looks like and when this exactly happens.

Comment: Are you running in an environment where you have a SOCKS proxy configured?